# SmartGWT - Cambiar el color de la fila al hacer click en un ListGrid

Tags: java, smartgwt

Estoy usando un ListGrid, cuando el usuario haga click en una fila quiero que el color de fondo de dicha fila cambie a uno elegido por mí.

Añado una imagen que muestra una fila con el color cambiado una vez que el usuario ha hecho click.
[image: Esto es lo que necesito.]

¿Cómo puedo conseguir que cambie el color tras un click?

Comment: Hola Daniel y bienvenido, ¿podrías añadir más información a tu pregunta? Qué has intentado, un ejemplo claro de lo qué quieres...

Comment: He reformulado la pregunta y añadido una imagen. Ademas encontré la solución y la he puesto como respuesta. Espero que se entienda ahora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo normal en estos casos es sobreescribir el método *getBaseStyle* del *ListGrid*, se hace 
así:

```
@Override
protected String getBaseStyle(ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum){
   if (listGrid.getSelectedRecord() == record){
      return "custom-color-CSS";
   }
   return super.getBaseStyle(record, rowNum, colNum);
}
```

Hay que recordar que lo que devuelve este método es una clase CSS que debe estar definida en algún lado.